# Greasemonkey replace code

Tags: javascript, html, replace, greasemonkey, userscripts

I want to replace `openProfileOrUnlockUser` with `openProfile` in elements like this:

```html
<a ng-href="/profile/CRYJIEjJGv+th/a/aQmDoFisAhE+LSldMLJbk1VCTJUJMeCqzFw0xZb9Q=="
   ng-click="user.openProfileOrUnlockUser(item._type)" 
   class="show overflow-hidden absolute-fill" 
   eat-click="" 
   href="/profile/CRYJIEjJGv+th/a/aQmDoFisAhE+LSldMLJbk1VCTJUJMeCqzFw0xZb9Q==">
```

What I have now is:

```
textNodes = document.evaluate("//text()", document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null); 
var searchRE = new RegExp('user.openProfileOrUnlockUser(item._type)','g'); 
var replace = 'user.openProfile'; 
for (var i=0;i<textNodes.snapshotLength;i++) { 
    var node = textNodes.snapshotItem(i); 
    node.data = node.data.replace(searchRE, replace);
}
```

but it doesn't work.

P.S. searched for like 2 hours and haven't got it working.

Comment: Not sure, but you might need to escape some characters in your regexp. try using this line instead of what you've got `var searchRE = /user.openProfileOrUnlockUser\(item._type\)/g;` You;ll need to add the extra bit onto your replacement text too i think.

Comment: Could be your xpath, doesn't `text()` only match the content of a node and not the actual node itself?

Comment: If i understand your situation correctly you don't need RegEx. Just apply replacement `node.data.replace("openProfileOrUnlockUser", "openProfile");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-click` is an attribute, not a text node so your xpath won't work.

The obvious choice would be `document.querySelectorAll`:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[ng-click*="openProfileOrUnlockUser"]'), 
    function(node) {
        node.setAttribute('ng-click', 
            node.getAttribute('ng-click').replace('openProfileOrUnlockUser', 'openProfile')
        );
    }
);
```